# Export data to CSV in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export

I need export data as CSV in rails appl. I found this plugin: https://github.com/crafterm/comma. Do you know about some better solution?

Comment: Looks pretty comprehensive and handles data relations, I'd say stick with **comma**

Comment: Comma does not work for me in rails3. I found https://github.com/econsultancy/csv_builder and it works well.

Comment: Can confirm that comma is not working in Rails 3.

Answer (score 38):

If using Ruby 1.9.x, then use CSV rather than FasterCSV and stick with the default delimiters.

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...           
  format.csv { render :layout => false }
end
```

show.csv.erb:

```
<%= this_is_your_view_helper_method.html_safe %>
```

controller_helper.rb:

```
require 'csv'

def this_is_your_view_helper_method
  CSV.generate do |csv| 
    Product.find(:all).each do |product|
      csv << ... add stuff here ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: FasterCSV actually became the standard CSV library in Ruby 1.9, so no need to download it, it's already there if you're on Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Works great with rails 3.x too.

Comment: Thanks @Fletch for the note! This answer has been downvoted twice and I have no idea why. If you downvote, please let me know why you're doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822422/output-array-to-csv-in-ruby) for using CSV in Ruby 1.9.x (which, as Fletch noted, includes FasterCSV but with slightly different syntax).