# Output array to CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

It's easy enough to read a CSV file into an array with Ruby but I can't find any good documentation on how to write an array into a CSV file. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 if that matters.

Comment: The answer you have is great, but let me urge you to not use CSV. If you don't have tabs in your data, tab-delimited files are much easier to deal with because they don't involve so much freakin' quoting and escaping and such. If you must use CSV, of course, them's the breaks.

Comment: @Bill, the CSV module neatly handles tab-delimited files as well as actual csv files. The :col_sep option lets you specify the column separator as "\t" and all's well.

Comment: here is more Info about CSV  http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/CSV.html

Comment: Using .tab files with this module is what I am doing, because opening this in Excel by accident would othrwise mess up the encoding…

Answer (score 391, accepted):

To a file:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("myfile.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

To a string:

```
require 'csv'
csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

Here's the current documentation on CSV: *(until 3.1.1 just replace 1.9.2)*

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Writing

###### while 3.1.2 up to latest *(3.2.2 as of this edit)*.

https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/csv/CSV.html

Comment: @David it's the file mode. "w" means write to a file. If you don't specify this, it'll default to "rb" (read-only binary mode) and you would get an error when trying to add to your csv file. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html for a list of valid file modes in Ruby.

Comment: Gotcha. And for future users, if you want each iteration to not overwrite the previous csv file, use the "ab" option.

Comment: See this answer for Ruby File IO Modes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682374/224707

Answer (score 76):

If you have an array of arrays of data:

```
rows = [["a1", "a2", "a3"],["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"], ["c1", "c2", "c3"]]
```

Then you can write this to a file with the following, which I think is much simpler:

```
require "csv"
File.write("ss.csv", rows.map(&:to_csv).join)
```

Comment: yeah but every time it rewrite the file , and not add the data at the end

Comment: @HumayunNaseer I haven't needed a situation where I was appending data to a CSV but you could certainly do that using the `mode: "a"` option for `File.write`.

Answer (score 45):

I've got this down to just one line.

```
rows = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'], ... ]
csv_str = rows.inject([]) { |csv, row|  csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join("")
#=> "a1,a2,a3\nb1,b2,b3\nc1,c2,c3\n"
```

Do all of the above **and** save to a csv, in one line.

```
File.open("ss.csv", "w") {|f| f.write(rows.inject([]) { |csv, row|  csv << CSV.generate_line(row) }.join(""))}
```

NOTE:

To convert an active record database to csv would be something like this I think

```
CSV.open(fn, 'w') do |csv|
  csv << Model.column_names
  Model.where(query).each do |m|
    csv << m.attributes.values
  end
end
```

---

Hmm @tamouse, that gist is somewhat confusing to me without reading the csv source, but generically, assuming each hash in your array has the same number of k/v pairs & that the keys are always the same, in the same order (i.e. if your data is structured), this should do the deed:

```
rowid = 0
CSV.open(fn, 'w') do |csv|
  hsh_ary.each do |hsh|
    rowid += 1
    if rowid == 1
      csv << hsh.keys# adding header row (column labels)
    else
      csv << hsh.values
    end# of if/else inside hsh
  end# of hsh's (rows)
end# of csv open
```

If your data isn't structured this obviously won't work

Comment: I pulled in a CSV file using CSV.table, did some manipulations, got rid of some columns, and now I want to spool the resulting Array of Hashes out again as CSV (really tab-delimited). How to? https://gist.github.com/4647196

Comment: hmm...that gist is somewhat opaque, but given an array of hashes, all with the same number of k/v pairs and the same keys, in the same order...

Comment: Thanks, @boulder_ruby. That will work. The data is a census table, and that gist is rather opaque looking back at it. :) It's basically extracting certain columns from the original census table into a subset.

Comment: You're misusing `inject` here, you really want to use `map`. Also, you don't need to pass an empty string to `join`, as this is the default. So you could shrink it even further to this: `rows.map(&CSV.method(:generate_line).join`

Comment: @iGEL, you are correct but you have missed a `(` . `rows.map(&CSV.method(:generate_line)).join`

Comment: Your second example is overcomplicated, as CSV library is quite powerful. `CSV.generate(headers: hsh.first&.keys) { |csv| hsh.each { |e| csv << e } }` generates an equivalent CSV.

Answer (score 27):

If anyone is interested, here are some one-liners (and a note on loss of type information in CSV):

```
require 'csv'

rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]                    # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

# To CSV string
csv = rows.map(&:to_csv).join             # "1,2,3\n4,5\n"

# ... and back, as String[][]
rows2 = csv.split("\n").map(&:parse_csv)  # [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"]]

# File I/O:
filename = '/tmp/vsc.csv'

# Save to file -- answer to your question
IO.write(filename, rows.map(&:to_csv).join)

# Read from file
# rows3 = IO.read(filename).split("\n").map(&:parse_csv)
rows3 = CSV.read(filename)

rows3 == rows2   # true
rows3 == rows    # false
```

Note: CSV loses all type information, you can use JSON to preserve basic type information, or go to verbose (but more easily human-editable) YAML to preserve all type information -- for example, if you need date type, which would become strings in CSV & JSON.

Answer (score 11):

Building on @boulder_ruby's answer, this is what I'm looking for, assuming `us_eco` contains the CSV table as from my gist.

```
CSV.open('outfile.txt','wb', col_sep: "\t") do |csvfile|
  csvfile << us_eco.first.keys
  us_eco.each do |row|
    csvfile << row.values
  end
end
```

Updated the gist at https://gist.github.com/tamouse/4647196

Answer (score 3):

Struggling with this myself.  This is my take:

https://gist.github.com/2639448:

```
require 'csv'

class CSV
  def CSV.unparse array
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      array.each { |i| csv << i }
    end
  end
end

CSV.unparse [ %w(your array), %w(goes here) ]
```

Comment: Btw, beware of multi-dimensional arrays in pry on JRuby. `[ %w(your array), %w(goes here) ]` won't look pretty. https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/568