# How to dump a 2D array directly into a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have this 2D array:

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I usually do:

```
CSV.open(file) do |csv| 
  arr.each do |row| 
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Is there any easier or direct way of doing it other than adding row by row?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822422/output-array-to-csv-in-ruby

Comment: What you have is already pretty darn easy for you the programmer. Are you (prematurely) worried about the performance of adding the rows one at a time?

Comment: @Phrogz No I am not worrying about performance. I wanna make life easier but not sure if there is already something I can use or i will have to do it myself.

Comment: Like CSV.read method, it can read csv file and parse to a 2D array, but why there is no inverse of that?

Comment: In older versions of Ruby there used to be CSV.dump...it's gone now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that your array is just numbers (no strings that potentially have commas in them) then:

```
File.open(file,'w'){ |f| f << arr.map{ |row| row.join(',') }.join('\n') }
```

One enormous string blatted to disk, with no involving the CSV library.

Alternatively, using the CSV library to [correctly escape each row](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/):

```
require 'csv'
# #to_csv automatically appends '\n', so we don't need it in #join
File.open(file,'w'){ |f| f << arr.map(&:to_csv).join }
```

If you have to do this often and the code bothers you, you could monkeypatch it in:

```
class CSV
  def self.dump_array(array,path,mode="rb",opts={})
    open(path,mode,opts){ |csv| array.each{ |row| csv << row } }
  end
end
CSV.dump_array(arr,file)
```

Comment: So there is no pre-defined method can do that? I will make a monkey patch then...

Comment: @texasbruce Your reading of the docs is as good as mine. I don't see one; do you?

Comment: Top version didn't work for me, embedded a bunch of literal "\n" strings into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer above by @Phrogz, while using the csv library and requiring to change the default delimiter:

```
File.open(file,'w'){ |f| f << arr.map{|x| x.to_csv(col_sep: '|')}.join }
```