# How to run and extract the mysql query data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run below query in a rails console and export the data in csv format ,

query

```
"select user.name,post.desc from user inner join post on user.id = post.user_id"
```

i am using below record to get the query result , but how to export the data into a csv .

```
def post_info()
  query = "select user.name,post.desc from user inner join post on user.id = post.user_id"
  output = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
  #how to export output data as csv 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Output array to CSV in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822422/output-array-to-csv-in-ruby)

### something like that.

```rb
query = "select user.name,post.desc from user inner join post on user.id = post.user_id"
output = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
CSV.open("./file.csv", 'w') do |csv|
  csv << %w(UserName PostDesc)
  output.each do |user_name, post_desc|
    row = [user_name, post_desc]
    csv << row
  end
end
```