# keep a version of an object before it's updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to keep a version of an object before it's updated.

For example:

This is the article on create:

```
#<Article:0x007fc32af4c910
 id:1,
 title: "Guitar",
 price: 300,
 buying_price: 50,
 created_at: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 >
```

This is an update of the article:

```
#<Article:0x007fc32af4c910
 id:1,
 title: "Guitar",
 price: 300,
 buying_price: 35,
 created_at: Sun, 17 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 >
```

This the another update of the article:

```
#<Article:0x007fc32af4c910
 id:1,
 title: "Guitar",
 price: 380,
 buying_price: 45
 created_at: Sun,17 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 14:39:21 UTC +00:00,
 >
```

See the the prices have changed, but I want to be able to report them all in an accounting table:

date  | buying_price | price

- 17 feb |50  |300|
- 18 feb |35  |300|
- 20 feb |45  |380|

*sorry I don't know how to create a table on markdown here*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Accounting table is a DB table

   You can use [previous_changes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes) do detect what changed and in a callback to update the accounting table.

   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
        after_save :log_to_accounting_table

   ```
    private 

    def log_to_accounting_table
      p previous_changes
      Accounting.create(....)
    end
   ```

   end

   Not related to your issue: I'm using [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) to track changes.
2. Accounting table is an Excel (what OP really wanted)

   You'll need a table to store all those changes, "old versions" as you call them.
   [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) will help you. Then all you need to do is to export data from the audits table to a csv. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053149/exporting-to-csv-in-rails) to learn how to export to excel.

Comment: Thanks  :)  I am not sure to understand sorry...  When I was talking about accounting table I meant a  kind of excel table (not a DB table) to list my articles and their different states.
I dont' understand how I will display my "old" versions and their date ( could be several)

Comment: many thanks, I will look at this and come back to accept the answer :)